# How to use filter on cloud/roleName in Azure Application Insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitor-workbooks

I created the "New Failures Analysis" workbook in Azure Application Insights. In that, I added a custom chart using the below query to display the count of requests, failures, exceptions, etc. based on the **cloud/roleName** property.

```
{
  "type": 10,
  "content": {
    "chartId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "version": "MetricsItem/2.0",
    "size": 3,
    "chartType": 0,
    "resourceType": "microsoft.insights/components",
    "metricScope": 0,
    "resourceIds": [
      "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    ],
    "timeContext": {
      "durationMs": 86400000
    },
    "metrics": [
      {
        "namespace": "microsoft.insights/components",
        "metric": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/count",
        "aggregation": 7
      },
      {
        "namespace": "microsoft.insights/components",
        "metric": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/failed",
        "aggregation": 7
      },
      {
        "namespace": "microsoft.insights/components",
        "metric": "microsoft.insights/components--exceptions/count",
        "aggregation": 7
      },
      {
        "namespace": "microsoft.insights/components",
        "metric": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/duration",
        "aggregation": 4
      },
      {
        "namespace": "microsoft.insights/components",
        "metric": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/rate",
        "aggregation": 4
      }
    ],
    "gridFormatType": 2,
    "filters": [
      {
        "key": "cloud/roleName",
        "operator": 0,
        "values": [
          "xxxxxxxxx"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "gridSettings": {
      "formatters": [
        {
          "columnMatch": "Subscription",
          "formatter": 5
        },
        {
          "columnMatch": "Name",
          "formatter": 5,
          "formatOptions": {
            "linkTarget": "Resource"
          }
        },
        {
          "columnMatch": "Segment",
          "formatter": 5
        },
        {
          "columnMatch": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/count",
          "formatter": 8,
          "formatOptions": {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 5000,
            "palette": "green"
          },
          "numberFormat": {
            "unit": 0,
            "options": {
              "style": "decimal"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "columnMatch": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/count Timeline",
          "formatter": 5
        },
        {
          "columnMatch": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/failed",
          "formatter": 8,
          "formatOptions": {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 20,
            "palette": "orangeRed"
          },
          "numberFormat": {
            "unit": 0,
            "options": {
              "style": "decimal"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "columnMatch": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/failed Timeline",
          "formatter": 5
        },
        {
          "columnMatch": "microsoft.insights/components--exceptions/count",
          "formatter": 8,
          "formatOptions": {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 20,
            "palette": "yellowOrangeRed"
          },
          "numberFormat": {
            "unit": 0,
            "options": {
              "style": "decimal"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "columnMatch": "microsoft.insights/components--exceptions/count Timeline",
          "formatter": 5
        },
        {
          "columnMatch": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/duration",
          "formatter": 8,
          "formatOptions": {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 1000,
            "palette": "yellowGreenBlue"
          }
        },
        {
          "columnMatch": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/duration Timeline",
          "formatter": 5
        },
        {
          "columnMatch": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/rate",
          "formatter": 8,
          "formatOptions": {
            "min": 0,
            "palette": "blueGreen"
          },
          "numberFormat": {
            "unit": 31,
            "options": {
              "style": "decimal"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "columnMatch": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/rate Timeline",
          "formatter": 5
        }
      ],
      "rowLimit": 10000,
      "labelSettings": [
        {
          "columnId": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/count",
          "label": "Requests"
        },
        {
          "columnId": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/count Timeline",
          "label": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/count (Count) Timeline"
        },
        {
          "columnId": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/failed",
          "label": "Failed"
        },
        {
          "columnId": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/failed Timeline",
          "label": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/failed (Count) Timeline"
        },
        {
          "columnId": "microsoft.insights/components--exceptions/count",
          "label": "Exceptions"
        },
        {
          "columnId": "microsoft.insights/components--exceptions/count Timeline",
          "label": "microsoft.insights/components--exceptions/count (Count) Timeline"
        },
        {
          "columnId": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/duration",
          "label": "Avg Response Time"
        },
        {
          "columnId": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/duration Timeline",
          "label": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/duration (Average) Timeline"
        },
        {
          "columnId": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/rate",
          "label": "Request Rate"
        },
        {
          "columnId": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/rate Timeline",
          "label": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/rate (Average) Timeline"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "name": "metric - 01"
}
```

The above query worked fine a few days ago, but suddenly this query is not giving any results, even though the logs are available in the Azure Application Insights for the specific cloud/roleName property.

Comment: where is the query?

Comment: there's no query there, that's a workbook metrics step, not a query step.  It uses Azure Metrics as the data source, not Log Analytics.  That being said, it SHOULD still work?

Comment: Can anyone suggest how to display the total number of requests, failed requests, exceptions, average response time, and request rate for specific cloud role name over the past 24 hours using the "New Failures Analysis" workbook?

Answer (score 1):

The metric ID doesn't look quite right. When I add a metric in Workbooks, say, failed requests, I get the ID `"metric": "microsoft.insights/components-Failures-requests/failed"` instead of `"metric": "microsoft.insights/components--requests/failed"`. I'm curious how this Workbook JSON was generated? I would recreate this metrics step again and check if the issue persists. If it does, also check if you are seeing no results in the Metrics blade as well. If the Workbook continues to show incorrect results afterwards, I would recommend submitting a support request.

Comment: I referred this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-supported#microsoftinsightscomponents documentation for the supported metrics.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the Workbook edit UI experience directly? The metric ID is unique to Workbooks and cannot be generally authored using the above documentation.